# Can Install a VM on a USB stick?

Tags: linux, usb, virtual-machine, vmware, kali-linux

I've been using a VM on my Windows now, for about 2 years, and been thinking could i somehow keep moving my VM from a computer to a other. The idea is that I could just move the stick around and around without for example having to use administrator rights.

The main idea I had is that, could i install VM Workstation fully on a USB and make all the needed Kali-Linux files store on the single USB stick.
(And just to clarify the goal, I dont want to make it a bootable USB device for Windows)

Hoze

Comment: You could save the virtual _disk_ to a USB stick (although the performance would be horrible) but your host machine will still need to have VMWare installed to run the VM.

Comment: @squillman Does the VMWare need administrator rights and is it possible to install the vmware on a stick and move it from there?

Comment: You need Admin rights to install VMware. You do not need host admin rights to install a machine. Better just to move the guest machine folder to another machine and install VMware on the new machine.

Comment: Hello @John so the situation is, I've got school "computer/tech" lessons now 3 times a week, and things I do is enumerating and bug bounties. The problem is, the computer I need to use, is the schools computer(That they gave us for 2 years),  which I wont be able to get admin rights on. So is there no way for me to get kali linux or any other os on the computer?

Comment: Probably not, but trying to install VMware Workstation AND guest on a USB stick will be slow. You would be able to chip a guest out of granite before it loads.

Comment: Okay, guess its not possible, thanks anyways @John

Comment: What you need as far as performance goes is a SSD or NVMe device with a USB adapter.

Now if you only have USB 2 ports its still going to be painful.
However with USB 3 ports it shouldn't be too bad.